# printings characters of the string skipping one character

Tags: python-3.x, slice

```
astring = "Hello world!"
print(astring[3:7:2])
```

Python prints out "l". Can anyone explain to me why?

Comment: It just works as expected. what do you expect then?

Comment: This might help: [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: Note: it prints `"l "`, not `l`. You missed the space because it looks like nothing.

Answer (score 2):

It actually prints out `l` . You can see this if you convert the sliced string to a list of characters before printing it:

```
print(list(astring[3:7:2]))
['l', ' ']
```

This makes sense, because `'l'` is the character at index 3, and `' '` is the character at index 5 (one step from 3, using step size `2`). The character at index 7 is not printed because the 'end' index of a slice is exclusive, not inclusive, and 7 is not less than 7.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I would like to understand what I can keep with this function, it doesn't make any sense for me

Comment: If I write   astring = "Hello world!"
print(astring[3:7])
print(astring[3:7:1])   Python prints out "lo w". Why print out also " " and "w"? It should be prints out only "lo", shouldn't it?

Comment: @AndreaCareggio, if you don't understand how string slicing works look at the link in ack's comment

Comment: @AndreaCareggio the three parts of a slice are `start`, `stop`, and `step`, all of which are optional. The slice `[3:7:2]` means "start at index 3, stop before index 7, and increase by 2 each time - so we end up with the characters at indices `3` and `5`. Meanwhile, the slice `[3:7:1]` (or just `[3:7]`) only increases by 1 each time, so we get the characters at indices `3`, `4`, `5`, and `6`.